# Simple Repository Pattern Question: How to query across multiple repositories efficiently?

Tags: entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

If you return IList(T) from your repository ...

How could you efficiently create SQL queries when you join the data together?

Is it REQUIRED to expose IQueryable / IEnumerable data structures for those methods?  This to me is bad.

Or

Am I missing some basic concept?

Right now I have a repository methods like:

```
IList<T> Get( Expression(...) filter, Expression(...) sort, int skip, int take)
```

where null indicates Get All.  This works very well until I want to find all Orders of a set of Customers without doing a query for each customer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have a repository for each Entity which returns IList<> which queries data immediately.  So, if I wanted to get a set of Customers and the corresponding Orders, I would need to somehow send the set of Customers in to the Order repository to act as a filter.  Heh, that's not a bad idea.  Otherwise, I would get the customers I want, and every single Order, then throw away all orders I wouldn't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not **required** to expose `IQueryable<T>`, but if you don't then you run into *exactly* the problem you're describing: You can't further compose the queries.

One solution is to put an entity service layer in front of the repository. The service layer is EF-ignorant, but can do LINQ projections. Projecting in LINQ results in a composed, single DB query.

I have a demo [here](http://halfpipe.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi @Craig Stuntz, I'd like to see your example. Is it available anywhere?